# Proving that $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ is a cube if $a^2 + 3b^2 = c^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

$\color{red}{\text{I forgot a vital condition on the integers $a,b$: they must be coprime!}}$

Consider $\omega = \frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, then the ring $\mathbb{Z}+\omega\mathbb{Z}$ is known to be a UFD (unique factorization domain). 
$\color{red}{\text{Suppose that $a,b$ are coprime integers. }}$
I was able to show that $a + b\sqrt{-3}$ and $a - b\sqrt{-3}$ ($a,b$ integers) only have units as common divisors. Moreover, it is given that $a^2+3b^2 = c^3$ for an integer $c$. From this, I found that 
$$(a + b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3}) = c^3$$
so looking at the unique factorization, I find that 
$$a+b\sqrt{-3} = u(d + e\omega)^3$$
for some integers $d,e$ and $u$ a unit. I know the units in $\mathbb{Z}+\omega\mathbb{Z}$ are given by $\{\pm1, \pm\omega, \pm\omega^2\}$. Because of the structure of the exercise which was given, I know I should be able to show that $a + b\sqrt{-3}$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z}+\omega\mathbb{Z}$, which I an show if the unit would be a cube itself. However, I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. Any hints?

**edit:**
Perhaps I should give some more details on the exercise: $\color{red}{\text{The purpose is to show that } a + b\sqrt{-3} \text{ can be written as}  (d + e\sqrt{-3})^3}$. In class, we saw that $\mathbb{Z}+\omega\mathbb{Z}$ is an Euclidean ring. The exercise consists out of multiple parts:

In part 1, we have shown that in a UFD it holds that if $ab = c^p$ (for $a,b,c$ elements in this UFD) for some integer $p$ larger or equal to $2$ and $g = \text{gcd}(a,b)$, then there exists a unit $d$ and an element $x$ in the UFD such that $a = dx^p$ en $d \mid g^{p-1}$.

In part 2, we have shown that if $x$ is a cube in $\mathbb{Z} + \omega\mathbb{Z}$, then it is in $\mathbb{Z} + \sqrt{-3}\mathbb{Z}$.

Part $3$ is the question where I have trouble with. From part $1$, I know that 
$$a + b\sqrt{-3} = dx^3$$
with $d$ a unit (since $\text{gcd}(a+b\sqrt{-3}, a-b\sqrt{-3})$ is a unit). Now if I could show that $d$ is a cube itself, then I coul go on.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but if such an unit $ d $ were a cube, then it should be a cube of some other unit so we just need to check that for any $ x \in \{ \pm 1, \pm \omega, \pm \omega^{2}\} $ there exists an $ y \in \{ \pm 1, \pm \omega, \pm \omega^{2}\} $ such that $ x=y^{3} $. This clearly works for $ \pm 1$ but doesn't work for $  \pm \omega $ or for $ \pm \omega^{2} $. So you must show that $ d \in \{ \pm 1\} $.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+b\sqrt{-3}=up_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\dotsm p_r^{m_r}$ and $a-b\sqrt{-3}=vq_1^{n_1}q_2^{n_2}\dotsm q_s^{n_s}$, where $p_i$ and $q_j$ are primes in your ring (with $p_i$ and $q_j$ not associate), $u$ and $v$ are units.

Then
$$
c^3=(a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3})=
uvp_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\dotsm p_r^{m_r}
q_1^{n_1}q_2^{n_2}\dotsm q_s^{n_s}
$$
This is a factorization into primes, so the integers $m_i$ and $n_j$ are all multiples of $3$, by uniqueness of the factorization. Therefore
$$
a+b\sqrt{-3}=ux^3
$$
for some $x$ in the ring and $u$ a unit.

This cannot be reduced to $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ being a cube. Consider
$$
(2+2\omega)^3=-8
$$
Then
$$
\omega(2+2\omega)^3=-8\omega=4+4\sqrt{-3}
$$
is of the form $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ with $a$ and $b$ integers, but is not a cube, because $\omega$ is not a cube.

Comment: You are absolutelly right... Still, the way the exercise was built screams to do something in this direction... But this gives a nice counterexample, so I will need to try something else.

Comment: I forgot an utmost important condition on the $a,b$: they should be coprime... I am really sorry that I forgot to mention this :(

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $(a + \sqrt{-3}b)$ and $(a - \sqrt{-3}b)$ are coprime and thus exists an $x$ in $\mathbb{Z} + \omega \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a + \sqrt{-3}b) = x^3$, from there you can use your second part.

Comment: that's what I did, but this gives you that it is a cube up to a unit.